# Gparted gives me the following error when I connect SD card - libparted error (read error / unrecognized disk label)

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, gparted, format, sd-card

I am trying to format my SD card with Gparted and cannot get it done because I get the below message.
The only way I can get rid of this message is removing the SD card

[image]

/dev/sdc  cannot be seen in the terminal

[image]

Output of `sudo parted -l` is below (I skipped the output for my SSD and HDD)

```
Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label
Model: Generic- SD/MMC (scsi)                                        
Disk /dev/sdc: 2022MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please post terminal output as text (formatted as code). The terminal output of `sudo parted -l` would be interesting. You can remove parts of the output which are about other disks if you're sure enough, otherwise just post the full output. Thanks

Comment: @ByteCommander done :)

Comment: If the SD card does not contain any valuable data, I would try to zero it out using `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4M`. Replace `/dev/sdX` with the actual device name of your SD card as shown in the output of `lsblk`. *The target disk you specify here will get completely overwritten, data rescue will be impossible! Be careful!*

Comment: @ByteCommander  thanks, I'm on the way and on mobile, will tell you the result when I get home

Comment: Try to format the disk with a camera, or a different device. If this works, then the SD card reader in your PC (or do you use an SD-card/USB adapter?) has issues.

Comment: @knb thanks, I use a USB adapter. tested with another SD card and the reader had no issues.

Comment: @ByteCommander I tried your command but it seemed going to take a long time without any progress on the terminal. I had to stop it before going for work, so I forced the terminal to close and after coming back from work  I reconnected the SD card,,, it's working...  thanks a lot..

Comment: @knb thanks, I fixed it before trying your idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SD card does not contain any valuable data, try to zero it out ( = overwrite the whole card and set all bits to 0) using this command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4M
```

Replace `/dev/sdX` with the actual device name of your SD card as shown in the output of `lsblk`.

> **WARNING**:
>   The target disk you specify here after `of=` will get completely overwritten, data rescue will be impossible! Be careful!

After that you should be able to partition and/or format it again. If it does not work, your SD card is physically damaged and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite the label with:

```
sudo tune2fs -L testing /dev/sdc
```

may not work, but if it does, then try to format it again.

Cheers, Al

Comment: I did not try this as I tried the ones in the comments above... Somehow the card is OK. Thank for the answer.